# Pandas Requires a Str object but received a float

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df_all_data:

                                      everything    file_names

0                                            ï»¿  v_merged.sql
1                   CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_merged]  v_merged.sql
2                                             AS  v_merged.sql
3                                WITH [stage] AS  v_merged.sql
4                                              (  v_merged.sql
5                                 SELECT --[row]  v_merged.sql
6                          [fssa_legacysystemid]  v_merged.sql
7                                        ,[A_ID]  v_merged.sql
8                                  ,[vendorcode]  v_merged.sql
9                           ,NULL AS [lpinumber]  v_merged.sql
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: ("descriptor 'startswith' requires a 'str' object but received a 'float'", 'occurred at index everything')
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? I thought my everything column is a `str` or `object` type?

Edit #1:

This is the code that caused this error:

```
df_all_data = df_all_data[~df_all_data.applymap(lambda x : str.startswith(x,'--')).any(1)]
```

Comment: You probably have `NaN`.  Try using `df_all_data = df_all_data.fillna('')` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Pandas has found `float` values, there's a good chance it's true. It could be that those values are null, i.e. `NaN` / `np.nan`. One simple workaround is to convert to `str` in your lambda function:

```
df = df[~df.applymap(lambda x: str.startswith(str(x), '--')).any(1)]
```

A better idea would be to convert to `str` via [`pd.DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and use `pd.Series.str` methods, which mimic exactly Python string methods:

```
df = df[df.astype(str).str.startswith('--').any(1)]
```